# Match and replace nested html tags with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'd like to forbit nesting of `<em>` and `<strong>` tags and remove the inner nested tag. Is this anyhow possible with regex?

```
<strong>Hello <em>World</em></stong>
```

should become

```
<strong>Hello World</stong>
```

Comment: Sorry, no. HTML is not a regular language. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Comment: I do not want to pares html. I'm sure it works. I already have seen a script doing something similar with regular expressions with negative lookaheads, however not able to figure it out again and do not find it any more on the web.

Comment: Do you want to do it in web page or with nodejs?

Comment: I'm doing it serverside on node and only for exports.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just removing any `<em>` tags inside of `<strong>` you can use the following javascript code to get the desired result.

```
(function(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      a[i].innerHTML = a[i].innerText; //Removing any innerHTML here.
    }
})();
```

Comment: This answer only work ins browser not on server side thus does not answer the question!

Comment: @Manuel In the server side he can simply use jquery, where `document` would be: 

`require(['*.html'],(html)=>{document=$(html)}`

Answer (score 0):

Because dom cannot be recognized by regular expression, I recommend to find other ways like using dom manipulating functions.

For example, `<Strong>`, `<strong>`, `<sTrong>`, `<strong class="a">`, `<strong clAss = '  a'>` ... are all the valid dom. You can even omit the closing tag or misspell it(like your example!). You cannot handle this all with regular expression.

But, if you already prepared perfectly parsed dom like your example, this regex might work.

```js
// single line only
"<strong>Hello <em>World</em></strong>".replace(/^<strong>(.*)<em>(.*)<\/em>(.*)<\/strong>$/gi, "<strong>$1$2$3</strong>");
>> <strong>Hello World</strong>
```

Comment: This is not accounting html structure and may delete tags out of context at a completely different part of the page since .* does not respect nesting.